# regex find substring and replace characters and update whole string

Tags: python, regex

From

```
string= this is, not good "type of ,question" to ask, on stackoverflow
```

I want to extract `"type of , question"` substring and replace `','` with `' '`.

with `re.findall()` it yields a list of characters between `" "` and with `re.search` it yields class object.

With `re.sub()` it replaces all `','` but I need them except the ones that are inside sub-string with double quotes.

Can anyone help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It sounds like you already tried using `re.findall`, `re.search`, and `re.sub`, yes? Please share the code for each of those attempts.

Comment: output: this is, not good "type of question" to ask, on stackoverflow

Comment: Is it `'string= this is, not good "type of ,question" to ask, on stackoverflow'` or `string = 'this is, not good "type of ,question" to ask, on stackoverflow'`?

Comment: What should happen if there are more than two quote marks in the string? What if there are an odd number of quote marks? What if there are two 'real' quote marks, and one escaped quote mark inside that quote?

Comment: if ' " ' in new_li1:
     print('still to mess', new_li1)
           
        sub_string = re.search(r'\""(.*?)\""', new_li1)
        print(sub_string)

Comment: @Kevin my data is pretty clear. The string that I have showed you is what my data has. Any how it would be good if there is a general solution for the question you asked.

Comment: If the only data the code needs to work on is the one example you gave, then you only have to do `result = 'this is, not good "type of question" to ask, on stackoverflow'`. If you're thinking "very funny, I actually need it to work on a variety of inputs", then that's exactly why I'm asking these clarifying questions :-)

Comment: Should you hit a wall with regex, then zoom one level out and use PyParsing http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/pyparsing/web/index.html

Comment: @DanielF one might even go one level out to pure python! :) `repl, newstring = False, ''; for c in string: if c == '"': repl = abs(repl - 1); if not (repl and c == ','): newstring.append(c)`.  Now excuse me while I punch myself in the face.

Answer (score 4):

Use regex capture groups:

```
import re
s= 'this is, not good "type of ,question" to ask, on stackoverflow'
re.sub(r'(".*?),(.*?")', r'\1\2', s)
```

output:

```
'this is, not good "type of question" to ask, on stackoverflow'
```

Explanation: `(stuff)` in regex stands for capture groups, `\1` and `\2` respectively substitutes the part before and after the `,` character within the quoted part of string. Please note this also works for multiple quotes within a single string as well.

Comment: this one worked perfectly for me. Thanks for helping me out @Rocky Li

Comment: Glad to be able to help

Comment: Very nice. In order to add the space (from the requirement `replace ',' with ' '`), add a space between `\1` and `\2`

Comment: This would only remove one instance of comma though, which is fair if that's all OP need.

Comment: Also unbalanced quotes will introduced problems. See `'this is, not good", "type of ,question" to ask, on stackoverflow'` yields `this is, not good"  "type of ,question" to ask, on stackoverflow`

Comment: @Idlehands This sled through my mind, I think your solution is cleaner for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Another way that gives you some flexibility is you can do it by two steps:

1. Find all the matches that are contained in quotations,
2. In each match look for and replace the `','`.

Example:

```
# define a pattern that gets you everything inside a double quote
pat = re.compile(r'"[^"]+"')

# re.sub the quote pattern and replace the , in each of those matches.
string = pat.sub(lambda x: x.group(0).replace(',',''), string)

# 'this is, not good "type of question" to ask, on stackoverflow'
```

The flexibility of this is it allows you to replace as many `','` as you need, and you can perform other changes as well once you have located all the double quote patterns.

Comment: This should be higher up. My solution does not address multiple `,` in a single quote, which is a big overlook on my part.

Answer (score 1):

How about a combination of `split()` and `replace()`? :

```
s = 'this is, not good "type of ,question" to ask, on stackoverflow'

splitted = s.split('"')
print(s.replace(splitted[1], splitted[1].replace(',', '')))

# this is, not good "type of question" to ask, on stackoverflow
```

*Note*: This works in this case, but does not work in cases where you have the exact same string within double quotes outside the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
b=""" "hello, howdy". sample text, text then comes "Another, double, quotes" """

for str_match in re.findall(r"\".*?\"",b):
    b = re.sub(str_match,re.sub(r","," ",str_match),b)

print(b)
```

output: "hello  howdy". sample text, text then comes "Another  double  quotes" '

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this will match all your requirements, but on the template you offer the following would return what you are looking for.

```
result = re.sub('("(?:[^"])*),((?:[^"])*")', r"\1 \2")
```

Comment: Rocky Li's answer is cleaner, tough.